# How to change an image multiple times while hovering on different texts

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am Designer making a portfolio website. I know basics of HTML and CSS. This is my home page [image: homepage]

What I want is when we hover on different text on right, different images get showed up in the red circle as a preview for that project. How is this achievable? Will I have to use JS for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you'll need javascript.

I'd use the `mouseenter` event. It triggers when the cursor enters the element.
The basic syntax for that is:

```
element.addEventListener("mouseenter", event => {
    // This executes when the cursor enters the element
    alert("Entered");
});
```

You'll just need to go through all the options on the right and for each add a listener that sets the image to something else:

```
for (let option of options) {
    option.addEventListener("mouseenter", event => {
        image.src = "/image-url.png"; // Somehow get the image url for this option
    }
});
```

For the getting of the specific image url - one of the ways is a `data-something` attribute on each option. I've made a simple example with that here: https://jsfiddle.net/8jb4p6qw/24/

Answer (score 0):

i would do something like this

```
    object.addEventListener("focus", function(){
      
            object.append('<div id="myid">info</div>');
    });
    
    object.addEventListener("focusout", function(){
    
     document.getElementbyId('myid').remove();
    
    
    });
```